# Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in WindowsBase.dll

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm having trouble having something update in my WPF UI. The same part of the code that's throwing the exception works just fine in the other function. Now, for some reason, I can't figure out it's not only throwing an exception, it is also not updating like I want it to. I want the UI elements in the `OnCPUDetEvent()` function to update based off of the timer I have set up.

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Management.Instrumentation;
using System.Management;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace HWDetCS
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for CPUBase.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class CPUBase : Page
    {

        // lists are better than arrays, fite me!
        public List<string> names = new List<string>();
        public List<string> values = new List<string>();
        public int i = 0;

        // Set up a timer to be enabled later
        public Timer CPUDetRefreshTimer;


        public CPUBase()
        {
            // Auto generated stuff, don't touch!
            InitializeComponent();

            // Actually run all the detection stuff
            CPUDet();

            // Start up the Timer, and get it ready
            CPUDetRefreshTimer = new Timer();
            CPUDetRefreshTimer.AutoReset = true;
            CPUDetRefreshTimer.Interval = 500;
            CPUDetRefreshTimer.Enabled = true;
            CPUDetRefreshTimer.Elapsed += OnCPUDetEvent;

        }

        // This thing does all the work
        public void CPUDet()
        {
            // Get the CPU Management class, this makes it the CPU we get info off of rather than nothing, because if it wasnt set to the CPU, it would error and break and cry a lot... dont change it.
            ManagementClass CPUClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_Processor");
            CPUClass.Options.UseAmendedQualifiers = true;

            // Set up a data collection to get the data off of, this and the next thing SHOULD NEVER BE IN A LOOP! IT WILL BREAK YOUR CPU LIKE A BALLOON!
            PropertyDataCollection dataCollection = CPUClass.Properties;

            // Get the instance of the class, for some reason this is required to work, dont touch AND DONT PUT IT IN A LOOP WHY CANT YOU LISTEN!?
            ManagementObjectCollection instanceCollection = CPUClass.GetInstances();



            // This is a loop, its very fragile, dont touch it, it gets the list of data we are collecting
            foreach (PropertyData property in dataCollection)
            {

                // adds the names into one nice readable-ish list!
                names.Add(property.Name);

                // loop through all the instances and grabs the actual data off of it
                foreach (ManagementObject instance in instanceCollection)
                {
                    // makes sure we dont get null reference errors, I HATE THOSE SO MUCH! I KNOW ITS NULL JUST SHUT UP!
                    if (instance.Properties[property.Name.ToString()].Value == null)
                    {
                        // if its null, dont add the actual property data, INSTEAD, add a string that says null so we know not to mess with it
                        values.Add("null");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // otherwise, go right ahead
                        values.Add(instance.Properties[property.Name.ToString()].Value.ToString());
                    }
                }
                // counting....
                i++;

            }



            // Debug stuff, dont release uncommented!
            // TODO: COMMENT THIS OUT!
            for (int x = 0; x < names.Count - 1; x++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(names[x]);
                Console.WriteLine(values[x]);
            }

            // Get the name
            CPUNameText.Content = values[29];
            // Get the manufacturer
            CPUManuText.Content = values[27];
            // Get the number of CORES (NOT THREADS!)
            CPUCoreCountText.Content = values[30];
            // Get the Family
            CPUFamilyText.Content = values[18];

        }

        public void OnCPUDetEvent(Object obj, ElapsedEventArgs args)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Event Fire!");

            // Get the current clock speed
            CPUClockSpeedText.Content = values[10] + "MHz";
            // Get the current Voltage
            CPUCVoltageText.Content = (Convert.ToDouble(values[11]) / 10).ToString() + " Volts";
        }
    }


}
```

Here is the XAML for the actual UI Page:

```
<Page x:Class="HWDetCS.CPUBase"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HWDetCS"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
      Title="CPUBase" MinWidth="1280" MinHeight="720">

    <Grid Background="Gray">
        <DockPanel>
            <UniformGrid Rows="6" Columns="2">
                <Label x:Name="CPUNameLabel" Content="CPU Name:" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FF007ACC" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                <Label x:Name="CPUNameText" Content="Label" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FF007ACC"/>
                <Label x:Name="CPUManuLabel" Content="CPU Manufacturer:" FontSize="36" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FF007ACC"/>
                <Label x:Name="CPUManuText" Content="Label" Foreground="#FF007ACC" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <Label x:Name="CPUClockSpeedLabel" Content="CPU Clock Speed:" Foreground="#FF007ACC" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <Label x:Name="CPUClockSpeedText" Content="Label" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FF007ACC"/>
                <Label x:Name="CPUCoreCountLabel" Content="CPU Core Count:" Foreground="#FF007ACC" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <Label x:Name="CPUCoreCountText" Content="Label" Foreground="#FF007ACC" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <Label x:Name="CPUFamilyLabel" Content="CPU Family:" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FF007ACC" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                <Label x:Name="CPUFamilyText" Content="Label" Foreground="#FF007ACC" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <Label x:Name="CPUCVoltageLabel" Content="CPU Current Voltage:" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FF007ACC"/>
                <Label x:Name="CPUCVoltageText" Content="Label" Foreground="#FF007ACC" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            </UniformGrid>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: You should add a try-catch block to see what's actually happening. We can't help you with just `InvalidOperationException`

Comment: provide the window.xaml too. if you have specific directions in app.xaml then either describe or put it too.

Comment: and put a comment here to notify us

Comment: I used a try-catch block on the 2 (4 if you include comments) lines that are throwing the exception and all it did was double the amount of spam I get in the output window in Visual Studio

Comment: >> "The same part of the code that's throwing the exception works just fine in the other function."      

I don't think we can't tell what part of the code is throwing and which function is working fine for you. Please elaborate.

Also, consider sharing the exception details, including the stack, message any inner exceptions.

Comment: @Vatsan, he already gave the complete code, no need for much info for now. and what he meant is CPUDet function.

Comment: @JustMATT, please look here on [A method running on a non-UI thread updates the UI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd85b3df.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you got is the result of an "access denied" error. Your function starts its life in a different thread than the GUI itself, as a result it is not allowed to change GUI elements.

It is described in this link: [A method running on a non-UI thread updates the UI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd85b3df.aspx)

Above link gives methods to run away from the problem. However, there is no single solution for your problem. The following is just one of them.  It does step-by-step changes you need to apply. (EDIT: I have added another solution in the next answer)

---

Add  `using System.ComponentModel;` to your headers. This is to use binds with changing properties. If needed, add the reference dll file.

Now use this heading for your class :

`public partial class CPUBase : Page,INotifyPropertyChanged`

Next step is adding notifiers. The code is used as is for .NET v4.0, consult to [INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged) how to use for other versions.

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
}
```

now create two property field to hold your changing values. Consult the above link for other versions.

```
string speed;
public string Speed
{
    get
    {
        return speed;
    }
    set
    {
        speed= value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Speed));
    }
}
string volt;
public string Volt
{
    get
    {
        return volt;
    }
    set
    {
        volt = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Volt));
    }
}
```

The rest is much easier now. just change these properties inside your function (extra `i` is to show it is working as the values don't show immediate changes) (Edit: Additions work but I don't think the code gets **active** `values`, I tried to decrease CPU freq, and result didnt change)

```
Speed = values[10] + "MHz"+i;
Volt = (Convert.ToDouble(values[11]) / 10).ToString() + " Volts"+i;
i++;
```

Now give you page a name and update labels by bindings to these properties.

```
<Page x:Name="CPUBaseMain ...
...
<Label x:Name="CPUClockSpeedText" Content="{Binding Speed, ElementName=CPUBaseMain}" ...
<Label x:Name="CPUCVoltageText" Content="{Binding Volt, ElementName=CPUBaseMain}" ...
```

Comment: @JustMATT, if this answer solves your problem and no one else gives another answer, will you please mark it as accepted?

Comment: wow, thanks, ill definitely try this out, ill be back in a bit!

Comment: @JustMATT, `NotifyPropertyChanged` method is just a bit different on .NET v4.5, so consult to the link I gave, if you use that or any other version in your project.

Comment: works great, thanks, now I just need to find a way to update my values list without destroying my CPU

Comment: @JustMATT, great to know it suits your needs. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

In my previous answer, I mentioned there is no single solution to this question. Here is another one which much simpler than the previous one. Just keep in mind that each different solution will have its advantages as well as its drawbacks.

---

This solution uses `Threading` methods of the `Windows` class itself. Subprocesses communicate with GUI with a dispatcher method, which is otherwise not permitted by the system. The dispatcher is used to get/set properties of GUI elements in foreign methods. The drawback is you need to write a new dispatcher line for every *separate/independent* work you do.

The solution is very simple:

First, add the namespace for `Threading` methods of `Windows` class.

```
using System.Windows.Threading;
```

Then, create an `Action`. To do this just wrap your getter/setter code fragments related to GUI in a new `Action` definition. this action can be defined just in place as well as anywhere your method can access.

```
Action dispatcherAction = new Action(() =>
  {
    // Get the current clock speed
    CPUClockSpeedText.Content = values[10] + "MHz";
    // Get the current Voltage
    CPUCVoltageText.Content = (Convert.ToDouble(values[11]) / 10).ToString() + " Volts";
  });
```

And finally, dispatch your action in the `OnCPUDetEvent`method. That is all.

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(dispatcherAction, DispatcherPriority.Normal);
```

---

If the code that needs to be dispatched is short as a few lines, then creating a new action outside is not necessary. But by doing this, you bind the action to the method calling it.

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(
    new Action (() =>
        {
            // Get the current clock speed
            CPUClockSpeedText.Content = values[10] + "MHz";
            // Get the current Voltage
            CPUCVoltageText.Content = (Convert.ToDouble(values[11]) / 10).ToString() + " Volts";
        }),
    DispatcherPriority.Normal                
    );
```